# Can't npm install in azure with pipeline when intalling bryntum grid

Tags: azure-pipelines, bryntum-grid

> npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with
> lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for
> lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it! npm ERR! code E404
> npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET
> https://registry.npmjs.org/@bryntum%2fgrid-trial - Not found npm ERR!
> 404  npm ERR! 404  '@bryntum/grid-trial@^5.1.1' is not in the npm
> registry. npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use
> the name yourself!) npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of
> 's' npm ERR! 404  npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
> npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing to the wrong repo. Bryntum uses a private repo so first you will have to log in to it:

```
$ npm config set "@bryntum:registry=https://npm.bryntum.com"
```

Full instructions can be found here: https://bryntum.com/products/grid/docs/guide/Grid/npm-repository